# What will be the output of the left join?

Tags: sql, left-join

I have 2 tables A and B.
Table A has 3 rows and one column having values 1, 1, 1.
Table B has 2 rows and one column having values 1, 1.
Upon applying left join, Table A left join Table B
The output I will receive is:
1, 1, 1.

Is it correct?

Comment: Create test data, write the actual SQL, and test it to find out if it works or not.

Comment: Say why you think you get that, with justification referencing authoritative documentation. Otherwise we have no idea why you think that so we can't explain where your thinking is right or wrong. PS Research is expected. Yes or no questions are not good questions. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No, your assumption is not correct. If you join on the columns you mention, you will get 6 rows (3 x 2), because every row matches each other.

### Table t1

| id_t1 | colx |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |

### Table t2

| id_t2 | coly |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 |
| 20 | 1 |

### Query

```
select *
from t1
left outer join t2 on t2.coly = t1.colx
order by t1.id_t1, t2.id_t2;
```

### Result

| id_t1 | colx | id_t2 | coly |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 20 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 10 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 20 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 10 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 20 | 1 |

You seem to misunderstand what a left outer join does. Each row in table t1 has two matches in table t2. You get these with a left outer join, but you also get them with an inner join. The difference between the two join types is when there is no match. Let's add another row to table t1:

| id_t1 | colx |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 2 |

There is no match in t2 for the value 2. An inner join would not show this row in the results. A left outer join in contrast will add the following row to your results:

| id_t1 | colx | id_t2 | coly |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2 | null | null |